# Playscape Unity Publishing Kit Error

Tags: unity-game-engine, playscape

I am integrating Playscape 1.11 SDK to my game in unity. I keep getting an error stating: `An error occurred while applying post-build logic: failed to apply patch to the .jar file`

I have checked to see if Android 19 and google-play-services are downloaded/installed in the SDK.

Comment: Can you please download the latest version 1.14 and update us if you still encounter this issue. if indeed you have this issue can you please update the question with full log?

Comment: It does the same with 1.14. Also which log? Unity has no log information sent to its console, is there an output file?

Comment: We discovered a bug in the latest SDK that we've fixed. Can you please download the fixed version (1.14.160) from the following link:
http://dashboard.playscape.com/download/PlayscapePublishingKit-unity.zip

Comment: Since updating I get a "An error occurred while applying post-build logic:Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. Noting in the project was changed; I used a script to remove all of the old package  assets first.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some files were missed. Check that you have removed all previous files of Playscape SDK before importing new version into your Unity project:

- /Assets/Plugins/Android/PlayscapeManifestFragments
- /Assets/Plugins/Android/PlayscapePublishingKit
- /Assets/Plugins/Playscape
- /Assets/Temp
- /Assets/StreamingAssets/fonts
- /Assets/StreamingAssets/level_up_icons
- /Assets/StreamingAssets/playscape
- /Assets/StreamingAssets/playscape_bootstrap
- /Assets/StreamingAssets/WelcomeMessage